# protobuf-net as wcf serializer with object in OperationContract

Tags: wcf, protobuf-net, netdatacontractserializer

I have project that uses wcf. Currently it uses NetDataContractSerializer. I want to migrate to protobuf-net. My service has folowing contract:

```
interface IRemotingServer
{
    [OperationContract]
    TypeConfig GetTypeConfig(string typename);

    [OperationContract]
    object ExecuteMethod(InstanceIdentifier instance, string methodName, object[] parameters);

    [OperationContract]
    object ExecuteGenericMethod(InstanceIdentifier instance, string methodName, object[] parameters, string[] genericTypes, string returnType);

    [OperationContract]
    object GetRemoteProperty(InstanceIdentifier instance, string propertyName);

    [OperationContract]
    void SetRemoteProperty(InstanceIdentifier instance, string propertyName, object value);      

    [OperationContract]
    ObjectDataPacket GetObject(InstanceIdentifier instance);

    [OperationContract]
    bool Connect();

    [OperationContract]
    bool Disconnect();
}
```

things goes fine, until i try call GetRemoteProperty method of my contract which return type is object. Using server traces i found, that server blows up with folowing message

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://www.mersoft.am/Remoting:GetRemotePropertyResult. The InnerException message was 'Type 'Mersoft.Remoting.InstanceIdentifier[]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfInstanceIdentifier:Mersoft.Remoting' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

So, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, returning `object` is going to be a huge problem for any serializer that isn't `BinaryFormatter` or `NetDataContractSerializer`; returning `object` just *doesn't work* and is *inappropriate* on a general purpose WCF boundary. protobuf-net, in common with most serializers (including `DataContractSerializer`, `XmlSerializer`, JSON.NET, etc) wants to know more than just `object`; simply, that is *not* enough information to deserialize in most scenarios.

As long as you return `object`, that just isn't going to work well with protobuf-net (or, as noted, most serializers). At the moment, `ProtoOperationBehavior` inherits from `DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior`; one possible option would be to write a version of this that defaults to `NetDataContractSerializer` rather than `DataContractSerializer` - this would mean that unknown types would be serialized by `NetDataContractSerializer` instead; of course, it still wouldn't use protobuf-net for `object`, *because it can't*.

Comment: @Gor short answer: no; which is why I didn't mention it ;p